# Can't set filter in pivot table - error 1004

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I'm working on a file with a pivot table. I need to select some filter with VBA, so I used the "macro recorder" to make this part. The whole macro, launch from a specific workbook (let's call it the *main file*), does the following things :

1. ask for a folder
2. for each file in the folder, open the file
3. select a given worksheet
4. set filters (see below)
5. save some of the data into the *main file*

Once I'm in the workbook that just has been opened, that's what I want to do

```
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(strFolder & strFileName)
wb.Activate
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("abcdfg").Select

With ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_1")
    .SlicerItems("item1").Selected = True
    .SlicerItems("item2").Selected = False
    .SlicerItems("item3").Selected = False
End With

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("my_table_name")
    .PivotFields("name1").CurrentPage = "value1"
    .PivotFields("name2").CurrentPage = "value2"
    .PivotFields("name3").CurrentPage = "value3"
End With
```

The first part with the SlicerCaches works well. But I can't go through the second part. I got an error 1004. However, **it used to work**, when I launch this part from a module in the workbook that contains the table (not the *main file*). Doesn't work anymore, even if I changed nothing !
It's really getting on my nerves since I've got this piece of code by recording it !

Have you got any idea to solve this? I've got through a lot of forums and questions but didn't find anything so far.

Thanks a lot for your help (and excuse my English please)

Comment: Change `ActiveWorkbook` to `wb`, and `ActiveSheet`, to `wb.Worksheets("abcdfg")`?

Comment: thanks for your help, but it doesn't change anything

Comment: `.PivotTables(1)` instead of `.PivotTables("my_table_name")`?

Comment: Still nothing. Actually if I try a `ClearAllFilters` it works, so I don't think it's about the selection of the table.

Comment: As I mentioned, the code used to work, so the `name`and `value` are correct. Can't figure out what's wrong.
the error said "application-defined or object-defined"